# Libgdx: random image, like slide show for a loading screen

Tags: java, load, 2d, libgdx

I wanted to create an loading screen which will present a random image and switch/transition to the other. I would just like to ask for any suggestion on how i should properly implement this loadscreen with random images?

Comment: This community is for discussion about helping in out of some problems which you are not able to solve.

And not for getting answer without trying them.

At least mention your approach so that it can be optimised
Problems lie these may have thousands of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 methods as I can remember right now.

In first method you have to load those random images and while AssetsManager loads your assets , just pick any image on random and display it for some period of time and then switch to some other image.

In second method if the random images are loaded using assets manager only then use method
assets.manager.isLoaded(fileName) to know if your random image is loaded or not. If its loaded then draw it else draw previous image only.

And Essa Rebano , i have repeatedly told u in your previous questions also to provide more information . Even in this question you should have posted you research work that you have done for this problem and where you are stuck in .. It becomes difficult for us to know how much you know and wot where exactly the problem lies. I hope u understand . If there is anything you are not able to understand in above sol. then you are most welcome to ask :)